# No lee el scanf

Tags: c

Estoy intentando resolver un problema desde ayer, cuando llego al "if" e ingreso la cantidad de litros según el tipo de gasolina, no lee el scanf y directamente salta al "printf" donde debe pagar el cual da como mensaje 0.00. No sé por que no guarda la variable.

```
#define MAX 3

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char tipo, resp;
    char placa1 [MAX] [8];
    char placa [MAX] [8];
    char serial [MAX] [20];
    float litros1;
    float litros;
    int i, ix, mayor, resultado,  buscador;
    float precio, precio1, total1, total, acum_total, cont_sn_plomo, porc_final, cont_plomo, acum_total1, total_rec;
    
    mayor = 0;
    buscador =  0;
    cont_plomo = 0;
    cont_sn_plomo = 0;
    acum_total = 0;
    acum_total1 = 0;
    i = 0;

    printf("\nBienvenido a la estacion de servicio Magdalena\n");
    system("pause");
    
    printf("\nIndique el precio por litro de gasolina sin plomo de hoy\n");
    scanf(" %f", &precio);
    printf("\nprecio%f", precio);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    printf("\nIndique el precio por litro de gasolina con plomo de hoy\n");
    scanf(" %f", &precio1);
    printf("\nprecio%f", precio1);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    do
    {
    printf("\nIngrese la placa del vehiculo a surtir gasolina\n", i + 1);
    scanf("%s",&placa[i]);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    printf("\nIngrese el serial de la carroceria\n");
    scanf("%s",&serial[i]);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    printf("\nIngrese el tipo de gasolina que desea surtir (Con Plomo/Sin plomo) ---> (P/N)\n");fflush(stdin);  
    scanf("%c",&tipo);
    fflush(stdin);
    
        if(tolower(tipo) =='p')
        {
            printf("\nIngrese la cantidad de litros a surtir\n");
            scanf(" %f", &litros1);
             
            total1 = (litros1 * precio1);
            acum_total1 += total1;
            cont_plomo= cont_plomo + 1;
        
            
            printf(("\nDebe pagar un total de %.2f\t"),&total1, ("\tpor %.2f\t"),&litros1 ,("\tde gasolina\n"));
        }
            else if(tolower(tipo) == 'n')
            {
                cont_sn_plomo++;
                printf("\nIngrese la cantidad de litros a surtir\n");
                scanf("%f",&litros);
                //if (litros > mayor)
                //{
                //mayor == litros;
                //}
                
                total = (litros * precio);
                acum_total += total;
                printf(("\nDebe pagar un total de %.2f"),&total, ("por %.2f"),&litros ,("\tde gasolina\n"));
            }

    system("pause");
    //system("cls");
    
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n¿Desea ingresar datos de otro auto?\n");
    scanf("%c",&resp);
    
    }while(tolower(resp) == 's' && i < MAX);
    
    
    system("pause");
    //system("cls");
    
    porc_final == (acum_total1 * 100 ) / cont_sn_plomo ;
        if(cont_plomo > cont_sn_plomo)
        {   fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nLa gasolina mas solicitada fue la gasolina con plomo\n"); 
        }
            else if(cont_plomo < cont_sn_plomo);
            {   fflush(stdin);
                printf("\nLa gasolina mas solicitada fue la gasolina sin plomo\n");
            }
    
    system("pause");
    
    fflush(stdin);
    acum_total + acum_total1 == total_rec;
    printf(("\nSe recaudo un total de%f "),&total_rec ,("\tBs\n"));
    printf("\nEl procentaje de despacho de gasolina sin plomo fue de\n" "%d",&porc_final);
    printf("\nEl auto que se le despacho mas gasolina fue %d", &mayor);
    
    fflush(stdin);   
    
    system("pause");
        
    
    return 0;
}
```

Al terminar el programa imprime unos valores exagerados, algo como 6834889. Intenté limpiar el buffer después de cada printf pero siguio igual.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, debe prestar mas atención a las advertencias del compilador, primero le paso una lista de errores, aunque compila hacen que el código no funcione correctamente:

`#include <stdlib.h>`
`#include <ctype.h>`
Esto elimina varias advertencias de funciones de declaradas de manera implícita

`printf("\nIngrese la placa del vehiculo a surtir gasolina\n");`
Elimine i+1, colocarlo solamente si las comillas contienen %d

`scanf("%s",placa[i]);
Elimine &, placa es bi-dimensional, al usar placa[i] ya tiene un puntero en la lista de stings

`porc_final = (acum_total1 * 100 ) / cont_sn_plomo ;`
Se cambio el doble == por =

Se remplazo `if( (cont_plomo < cont_sn_plomo)` por `else`, se eliminó `;`, cuando Ud tine un condicional o un bucle seguido de un bloque que comienza con llaves no debe colocar `;` al cerrar paréntesis.

`total_rec = acum_total + acum_total1;`
Se cambio == por =, ademas se invirtió el orden los miembros de la igualdad

`printf(("\nSe recaudo un total de %f "),total_rec);`
Deben conincidir la cantidad de operadores % dentro del las comillas con la cantida de parámetros luego de las comillas, total_rec no es puntero, no necesita &

Hay por lo menos una docena de errores mas que puede detectar con las advertencias del complilador, mi consejo es que no escriba tanto código si`n probar pequeñas partes que vayan funcionando.
Abajo el código con la correcciones de todos los errores que le mencione u algunos mas

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX 3

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    char tipo, resp;
 //   char placa1 [MAX] [8];
    char placa [MAX] [8];
    char serial [MAX] [20];
    float litros1;
    float litros;
    int i, mayor; //, resultado;
    float precio_cp, precio_sp, total1, total, acum_total, cont_sn_plomo, porc_final, cont_plomo, acum_total1, total_rec;


    mayor = 0;
//    buscador =  0;
    cont_plomo = 0;
    cont_sn_plomo = 0;
    acum_total = 0;
    acum_total1 = 0;
    i = 0;

    printf("\nBienvenido a la estacion de servicio Magdalena\n");
    system("pause");

    printf("\nIndique el precio por litro de gasolina sin plomo de hoy\n");
    scanf(" %f", &precio_sp);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("\nIndique el precio por litro de gasolina con plomo de hoy\n");
    scanf(" %f", &precio_cp);
    fflush(stdin);

    do
    {
        printf("\nIngrese la placa del vehiculo a surtir gasolina\n"); // Elimine i+1, colocarlo solamente si las comillas contienen %d
        scanf("%s",placa[i]); // Debe eliminar &, como placa es bidimensional placa[i] ya es un puntero
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("\nIngrese el serial de la carroceria\n");
        scanf("%s",serial[i]);
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("\nIngrese el tipo de gasolina que desea surtir (Con Plomo/Sin plomo) ---> (P/N)\n");
        scanf("%c",&tipo);
        fflush(stdin);

        if(tolower(tipo) == 'p')
        {
            printf("\nIngrese la cantidad de litros a surtir\n");
            scanf("%f", &litros1);

            total1 = (litros1 * precio_cp);
            acum_total1 +=total1;
            cont_plomo= cont_plomo + 1;


            printf("\nDebe pagar un total de %.2f \tpor %.2f\t", total1, litros1);
        }
        else if(tolower(tipo) == 'n')
        {
            cont_sn_plomo++;
            printf("\nIngrese la cantidad de litros a surtir\n");
            scanf("%f",&litros);
            //if (litros > mayor)
            //{
            //mayor == litros;
            //}

            total1 = (litros * precio_sp);
            acum_total +=total1;
            printf(("\nDebe pagar un total de %.2f \tpor %.2f\t"), total, litros1);
        }

        system("pause");
//system("cls");

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n¿Desea ingresar datos de otro auto (s)?\n");
        scanf("%c",&resp);

    }
    while(tolower(resp) == 's' && i < MAX);


    system("pause");
//system("cls");

    porc_final = (acum_total1 * 100 ) / cont_sn_plomo ;
    if(cont_plomo > cont_sn_plomo)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nLa gasolina mas solicitada fue la gasolina con plomo\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nLa gasolina mas solicitada fue la gasolina sin plomo\n");
    }

    system("pause");

    fflush(stdin);
    total_rec = acum_total + acum_total1;
    printf(("\nSe recaudo un total de %f "),total_rec);
    printf("\nEl procentaje de despacho de gasolina sin plomo fue de\n %f", porc_final);
    printf("\nEl auto que se le despacho mas gasolina fue %d", mayor);

    fflush(stdin);

    system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Buenas tardes amigo, muchas gracias por la ayuda. Es de mis primeros codigos y aún estoy aprendiendo, le agradezco.